# Работа с многопоточностью C#

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Thread(() => T()).Start();
    }
    public void T()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            t.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(t.Text) + 1).ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

я начинаю работать с многопоточностью и не знаю как исправить ошибку System.InvalidOperationException: "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток."

в строке
                t.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(t.Text) + 1).ToString();

Comment: `t.Text` это что?

Comment: t это TextBlock

Comment: вы можете использовать контролы пользовательского интерфейса только в UI потоке.

Answer (score -2):

Самый простой и нарушающий все основы ООП метод , это прописать в начале потока

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Comment: а разве я могу добавить библиотеку System.Windows.Forms в wpf